# Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=https

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Getting the below error when running a Selenium Webdriver Java testng project through Jenkins.

> 1521293224017 geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1 1521293224023
>   geckodriver   INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:6456
>   1521293224532   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.N9dbtg3hV9Yu"
>   *** You are running in headless mode.
>
> (firefox:10487): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
>       Using the fallback 'C' locale.
>   Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag 1521293225196    Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
>   Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
>   1521293227486   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 34041 1521293227568   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
>   Mar 17, 2018 1:27:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
>   Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
>   [ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 4, Time elapsed: 6.026 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
>   Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=https%3A//192.168.197.10/login.html&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20at%20192.168.197.10.
>   Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
>   System info: host: 'kd-autotest', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-31-generic', java.version: '9.0.4'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 59.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: true, moz:processID: 10487, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.N9dbtg..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.4.0-31-generic, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
>   Session ID: 83f17f89-eed2-467d-8381-f3c34a335c57
>       at

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reached error page: about:neterror when trying to navigate to other tabs if there is a form submit under that tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900844/reached-error-page-aboutneterror-when-trying-to-navigate-to-other-tabs-if-ther)