# Connection Reset Error - Flask with Splinter/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, flask, pytest, splinter

I'm working on setting up some tests for a Flask web app using Splinter/pytest.
I'm encountering an issue where the browsers return a 500 Error (connection was reset) when testing one of the methods (which involves submitting a form/POST request), which works fine if I manually access the page.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 - have tried both chromium (chromedriver) and firefox.

A test for a similar page (also using a post request) works fine.

Greatly appreciate any input.

**views.py**

```
@AUTH.route("/signup", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    """
    Processes the signup form
    :return: renders template
    """
    form = SignupForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    _user = User(email=form.email.data,
                 username=form.username.data,
                 displayname=form.display_name.data,
                 password=form.password.data,
                 confirmed=False,
                 roles=[get_default_role()])
    db.session.add(_user)
    db.session.commit()

    token = generate_confirmation_token(_user.email)

    confirm_url = url_for('auth.confirm_email', token=token, _external=True)
    html = render_template('auth/activate.html', confirm_url=confirm_url)
    subject = "Please confirm your email"

    send_email.delay(recipients=_user.email, subject=subject, template=html)

    login_user(_user)

    flash('A confirmation email has been sent via email.', 'success')

    return redirect(url_for("auth.unconfirmed"))

    return render_template("auth/signup.html", form=form)
```

**tests.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def init_db():
    db.session.commit()
    try:
    db.drop_all()
    except OperationalError:
    pass
    db.create_all()

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def create_user(init_db):
    admin = Role.query.filter(Role.name=='admin').first()
    user = User(username="test", displayname="test", email="test@test.com", password="test", roles=[admin])
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return user


@pytest.fixture()
def browser(init_db):
    browser = Browser('firefox')
    yield browser
    browser.quit()


#THIS TEST WORKS
def test_login(browser):
    url = f'{SERVER}:{PORT}/auth/login'
    browser.visit(url)
    browser.fill('username', 'test')
    browser.fill('password', 'test')
    button = browser.find_by_id('login-submit')
    button.click()
    assert browser.is_text_present('Logged in successfully as test.')


#THIS TEST FAILS 500
def test_signup(browser):
    url = f'{SERVER}:{PORT}/auth/signup'
    browser.visit(url)
    browser.fill('username', 'test19233d')
    browser.fill('display_name', 'test')
    browser.fill('email', 'mail@example.com')
    browser.fill('password', 'test')
    browser.fill('password2', 'test')
    button = browser.find_by_id('signup-submit')
    button.click()
    assert browser.is_text_present('A confirmation email has been sent via email.')
```

[image]

**Edit:** added error trace

```
platform linux -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-3.9.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /home/dev/repos/samo-cms/tests, inifile:
plugins: celery-4.2.1collected 1 item

splinter-tests.py F
splinter-tests.py:90 (test_signup)
browser = <splinter.driver.webdriver.firefox.WebDriver object at 0x7f6fcfbf04a8>

    def test_signup(browser):
    url = f'{SERVER}:{PORT}/auth/signup'
    browser.visit(url)
    browser.fill('username', 'test19233d')
    browser.fill('display_name', 'test')
    browser.fill('email', 'mail@example.com')
    browser.fill('password', 'test')
    browser.fill('password2', 'test')
    button = browser.find_by_id('signup-submit')
>       button.click()

splinter-tests.py:100: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py:633: in click
    self._element.click()
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:80: in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:633: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f6fcfbcd278>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Reached error page: about:neterror?e=netReset&u...tate@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:273:21\\nhandleEvent@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:241:9\\n"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response):
    """
    Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

    :Args:
     - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
       object.

    :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
    """
    status = response.get('status', None)
    if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
        return
    value = None
    message = response.get("message", "")
    screen = response.get("screen", "")
    stacktrace = None
    if isinstance(status, int):
        value_json = response.get('value', None)
        if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
            import json
            try:
                value = json.loads(value_json)
                if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                    value = value['value']
                status = value.get('error', None)
                if status is None:
                    status = value["status"]
                    message = value["value"]
                    if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                        value = message
                        message = message.get('message')
                else:
                    message = value.get('message', None)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
    if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
        exception_class = NoSuchElementException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
        exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
        exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
    elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
        exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
        exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
        exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
        exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
        exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
        exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
        exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
        exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
    elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
        exception_class = JavascriptException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
        exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
        exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
        exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
        exception_class = ScreenshotException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
        exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
        exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
        exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
        exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
        exception_class = UnknownMethodException
    else:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    if value == '' or value is None:
        value = response['value']
    if isinstance(value, basestring):
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, value)
        raise exception_class(value)
    if message == "" and 'message' in value:
        message = value['message']

    screen = None
    if 'screen' in value:
        screen = value['screen']

    stacktrace = None
    if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
        stacktrace = []
        try:
            for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                if line:
                    file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                if 'className' in frame:
                    meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                msg = msg % (meth, file)
                stacktrace.append(msg)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
        raise exception_class(response, message)
    elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
        alert_text = None
        if 'data' in value:
            alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
        elif 'alert' in value:
            alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=netReset&u=http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A5000/auth/signup&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=The%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20was%20reset%20while%20the%20page%20was%20loading.

../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: WebDriverException
```

Comment: Upadate the question with the error stack trace

Comment: @DebanjanB added error stack trace. Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a _Network Error_ check this discussion [Reached error page: about:neterror when trying to navigate to other tabs if there is a form submit under that tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900844/reached-error-page-aboutneterror-when-trying-to-navigate-to-other-tabs-if-ther/47902113#47902113)