# tbselenium tor browser unable to get url on ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, tor-browser-bundle

I am trying to use Tor browser with selenium and python on ubuntu. Browser is opening but showing proxy error. 
Here is code I am trying:

```
from time import sleep
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver

driver = TorBrowserDriver("/tor/tor-browser-linux32-8.0.3_en-US/tor-browser_en-US/")
driver.get('https://www.whatismyip.com/')
```

Exception got in the terminal is-

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure&u=https%3A//www.whatismyip.com/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20proxy%20server%20that%20is%20refusing%20connections.
```

Message shown on tor browser is:
https://pasteboard.co/HKYjivJ.png

Comment: did link opens up manually

Comment: yes... when open browser manually its working fine. with firefox and chrome code also working. problem is with tor.

Comment: Read more on <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900844/reached-error-page-aboutneterror-when-trying-to-navigate-to-other-tabs-if-ther>