# Selenium stopped working with Firefox, works with Safari

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been using Selenium with Python 3 for a while. Yesterday it stopped working. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, but it hasn't worked. I enabled the driver for Safari, and that works, but I don't know what changed. I tried going to a different project that I haven't used in a while but functioned, thinking my code threw it off, but it doesn't work either. I know there are other posts out there similar to this, but they haven't been helpful and I wasn't sure if I should contact Mozilla/Selenium about this issue. Here are my details:

```
Python 3.7.1
Django 2.1
Firefox 64
Selenium 3.141.0
Geckodriver 0.23.0
```

I am running these in a virtual environment. Any more questions, let me know. Really confused as to what broke.

This is all of the code related to launching the browser:

```
class FunctionalTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()


    def get_page(self, url_extention, window=None):
        window_size = [900, 700]
        if window == 'xs':
            window_size = [500, 700]
        elif window == 'sm':
            window_size = [700, 500]
        elif window == 'md':
            window_size = [900, 700]
        elif window == 'lg':
            window_size = [1024, 768]
        elif window == 'xl':
            window_size = [1400, 800]

        return (
            self.browser.get(
                self.live_server_url + url_extention
            ),
            self.browser.set_window_size(
                window_size[0],
                window_size[1]
            )
        )

class PageFunctionTest(FunctionalTest):

    def test_customer_page(self):
        self.get_page('/customer/profile/1/', window='xs')
        # I also tried this just to check:
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
```

Basically the browser opens, throws an error and then quits. This is what shows in the browser window:

> address bar: http//localhost:59905/customer/profile/1/
>
> browser error: Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:59905.

And this is the traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "tests/functional_tests/test_function_profile_update_phone_number.py",
>   line 21, in test_update_profile_phone_number
>       self.get_page(f'/customer/profile/1/', window='xs')   File "/base_tests/base_FunctionalTest.py", line 70, in get_page
>       self.live_server_url + url_extention   File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 333, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})   File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error
>   page:
>   about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=http%3A//localhost%3A59905/customer/profile/1/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20at%20localhost%3A59905.

Comment: did Firefox update?

Comment: It May have, not completely sure

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: @DebanjanB, updated

Comment: @CarlBrubaker Your main issue seems to be **selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror**. Checkout this discussion [Reached error page: about:neterror when trying to navigate to other tabs if there is a form submit under that tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900844/reached-error-page-aboutneterror-when-trying-to-navigate-to-other-tabs-if-ther/47902113#47902113)