# Firefox cannot establish a connection using a WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open up a log in page of a certain website using this code below:

```
print('Setting up proxy...')
selenium_proxy = webdriver.Proxy()
selenium_proxy.proxy_type = webdriver.common.proxy.ProxyType.PAC
selenium_proxy.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "./proxy.pac/"

print('Setting up headless display...')
global display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080),)

display.start()

print('Setting up profile...')
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
profile.set_proxy(selenium_proxy)
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')

global driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, capabilities=caps, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver', log_path='../Logs/geckodriver.log')
print('Opening browser...')
driver.get(url)
```

But I always encounter this Exception:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=https%3A<url>/account/login%3FloginType%3D&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20at%20<url>
```

Please note that my code works for some websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned *my code works for some websites*, basically when you try to access websites for which you don't have access rights you reach the *Network Error Page*:

[image: Network Error Page]

As the website/application is unreachable you see the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=https%3A<url>/account/login%3FloginType%3D&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20at%20<url>
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Reached error page: about:neterror when trying to navigate to other tabs if there is a form submit under that tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900844/reached-error-page-aboutneterror-when-trying-to-navigate-to-other-tabs-if-ther/47902113#47902113)

Comment: I'm only trying to access a log in page, do I need an access right for it already?